# Turn a basic line of code into a function in R

Tags: r, function

I have a basic line of code I've written and successfully executed:

```
if((new.weather.2013) > cut.point.90 | (new.weather.2013) < cut.point.015) {print("Weather is extreme")} else {print("Weather is not extreme")}
```

I would like to turn this into a repeatable function.  I'm still fairly new to R, and am having trouble getting it working.  Here is what I've tried so far (that hasn't worked):

```
weather.test <- function(test.weather)
{
  if((test.weather) > cut.point.90 |
       (test.weather) < cut.point.015)
return{print ("Weather is extreme")} else
return{print ("Weather is not extreme")}
}
```

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

EDIT: to elaborate, I'm taking a numerical value, running it through the function to determine whether the value is an extreme outlier (i.e. falls outside the cut points).  If it does fall outside those points, it's considered extreme, and I want to return that statement.  If it doesn't fall outside that extreme range, it's considered normal, and I want to return "weather is not extreme".  If you see the statement above, that does the same thing I'm trying to do here; I just want to make it a repeatable function.

Comment: please describe what "what doesn't work" means, precisely. Do you want a value return from the function, or do you want it to print a value, or both?

Comment: `return` uses parentheses, not curly brackets. BTW, there are many times using `return` is necessary and meaningful; though it is not incorrect to use it here, it is also not necessary to explicitly use it. The answers below show good alternatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want

```
weather.test <- function(test.weather) {
  ifelse((test.weather > cut.point.90 |
       test.weather < cut.point.015),
      "Weather is extreme",
      "Weather is not extreme")
}

#test
cut.point.90 = .9
cut.point.015 = .015
weather.test(c(0,.5,1))
```

ifelse() is a vectorized form of a standard if statement that can operate on vectors

Comment: This is naturally vectorized (good!), so that if `test.weather` is a vector of temperatures then this will return a vector of strings. If performance is ever an issue (`ifelse` performs relatively poorly compared with alternatives), you might consider subsetting with something like: `function(test.weather) { ret <- character(length(temp.weather)); idx <- ((test.weather > cut.point.90) | (test.weather < cut.point.015)); ret[idx] <- "extreme" ; ret[!idx] <- "not extreme" ; ret }`.

Comment: I have not found the claim that `ifelse`performs poorly to be correct. It often equals the performance of Boolean math methods. It certainly is the case that loops with `if(){}else{}` constructs are often very slow.